# Cropping frames Bottle under water with Shrinkwrap

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, export, shrinkwrap

I've created floating bottle under water and I've used a Shrinkwrap modifier for it. Bottle need to move with waves but it move kind strange. It looks like frame are cropping but I guess I have some issue with shrink-wrap modifier.

Can someone help with that? What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my project file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17VOxLBEJ3YYlRgSWaGo7sTOdWa30bNY-?usp=share_link

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe scale up the shrinkwraped plane a bit, set the bottle's origin at its geometry, and put the *Copy Location* and *Copy Rotation* influence values at 1 (it was 0.287 and 0.077):

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! I’ve animated it manual without modifier. Just ended it, but thank you for help. Would be nice to know that in the future 